# How to have a switch case scenario using String as condition?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a String that I need to get the last digit from and use switch cases according to that character.

```
String securityNumber= "4561";
String lastDigit = securityNumber.substring(securityNumber.length()-1);

switch (lastDigit) {
    case "0": System.out.println("0");
        break;
    case "1": System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case "2": System.out.println("2");
        break;
    case "3": System.out.println("3");
        break;
    case "4": System.out.println("4");
        break;
    default: System.out.println("def");
}
```

I am getting the "def" as a result but should be "1".

What am I doing wrong? How can I have a case scenario for each of the digits from an input of String "securityNumber"?

Comment: Is it just `def` or `1 2 3 4 def` all on separate lines?  You might benefit from a `break;` after each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `break` at the end of each case, otherwise the switch case will fall through and execute all the succeeding cases after the first one it matches. When I run it, it prints:

> 1 2 3 4 def

To fix this, here is the code:

```
String securityNumber = "4561";
String lastDigit = securityNumber.substring(securityNumber.length()-1);
switch (lastDigit) {
    case "0": System.out.println("0");
              break;
    case "1": System.out.println("1");
              break;
    case "2": System.out.println("2");
              break;
    case "3": System.out.println("3");
              break;
    case "4": System.out.println("4");
              break;
    default: System.out.println("def");
}
```

You also forgot a `;` at the end of the declaration for `securityNumber`, so it might have not compiled.